# Create new kendo datasource

Tags: angularjs, kendo-datasource

I am trying to create a new Kendo DataSource, but my data does not contain anything even though my result.data is an array of 14 items.

```
var request = new ShipmentManagementRequest(11736);
request.Carriers = vm.shipmentManagementRequest.Carriers;
request.RequestType = myChart.chartData.htmlID;
shipmentService.getBasicChartData(request)
    .then(function (result) {
        var chartDataEl = $('#' + myChart.chartData.htmlID).data('kendoChart');
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: result.data,
            sort: {
                 field: "date",
                 dir: "asc"
            },
            schema: {
                 model: {
                     fields: {
                        date: {
                            type: "date"
                        }
                     }
                }
            }
        });

chartDataEl.dataSource = dataSource;
```

Why is my data not being assigned?  My sort item seems correct.

Comment: Have you defined your columns in your grid settings? How are you loading result.data? Please post that code so we can help you troubleshoot.

Comment: This is not for a grid but a chart.  After I get my result.data back, I simple call refresh on the chart.  What code do you need to see?

Comment: @haakon319: I have updated my code to show what I am doing.  I am then just calling refresh on the chart.

Comment: Sorry I thought this post was about a grid when I saw the datasource :-/ I know that Telerik has great technical support included with the purchase of a license...